# How to upload BitmapData in flex 4 to server with preloader?

Tags: file-upload, flex4

Hy,

Im creating a upload component that do these things:

- select multiple images
- convert to BitmapData
- resize if is too large
- create a thumb(itemRenderer) and add it to a list

And the problem is how to upload them with a preloader for each image when a button is pressed. Anybody know how to do it?

thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the FileReference.browse() method to select the images and then upload them by using the FileReference.upload() method. That allows you to show an upload progress bar for every image.

[FileReference class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html)

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't allow for image resize if is big, and that was a requirement. Anyway the flex4 project has been discontinued..